# Force popup window ratio on resize

Tags: javascript

I know there maybe ugly hacks to achieve this, which is why I am asking this. Basically I have a video chat window, so I want to allow resizing of window, but I would like to force the ratio (so that it is maintained). I guess I can run a javascript which refreshes every X seconds and resizes the window.

Any good ideas? I don't mind if the hacks work on certain browsers and not on others. As many as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that you'll end up with the JavaScript fighting the OS during the resize operation.

How about putting the video into a DIV and use JavaScript to give that a certain aspect ration depending on the window size plus maybe a button "fit window to content" to get rid of the border?

Comment: already have the black border if the ratio gets skewed. but wanted to avoid that.